# How to protect view in Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla

In Joomla 3.0 what is the best way to protect a view based on the id. For example I have a url like:

/administrator/index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=unitversions&layout=edit&id=158733

I don't want a user to be able to see this page if they don't 'own' that id. I understand that the controller will authorise based on ACL but just redirects to a URL similar to the above.

I'm thinking a plugin might be the best approach? Perhaps using the onContentBeforeDisplay trigger.

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably the best way as is done in the CMS core files.

```
    // Check for edit form.
    if ($vName == 'category' && $lName == 'edit' && !$this->checkEditId('com_categories.edit.category', $id))
    {
        // Somehow the person just went to the form - we don't allow that.
        $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_UNHELD_ID', $id));
        $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');
        $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_categories&view=categories&extension='.$this->extension, false));

        return false;
    }
```